# Sending email from Trigger Not working fine

Tags: trigger, singleemailmessage, bulk

I have created a trigger that is supposed to be sending emails to the contacts on their update, based on certain criteria. It works fine for individual records, but on bulk testing, it is sending all the emails to just one person, for example, when I tried for 4 records, a single person received all the emails. The code is attached below, Can anyone please tell me what wrong I have done?

```
trigger SendEmailOptIn on Contact(after update){
    System.debug('Debug Log for inserted records'+trigger.new.size());
       if(SendEmailOptInHandler.firstRun){
          SendEmailOptInHandler.SendEmail(trigger.new);
          SendEmailOptInHandler.firstRun=false;
        }
    }
```

Handler Class :

```
public class SendEmailOptInHandler{
    public static boolean firstRun = true;
    public static void SendEmail(List<Contact> conLst){
    System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>firstRun: '+firstRun);
        String Id;
        String FirstName;
        String LastName;
        String ContactEmail;
        System.debug('Debug Log for conLst'+conLst);
        System.debug('Debug Log for conLst'+conLst.size());
        EmailTemplate et = [select body,htmlvalue from EmailTemplate where name=:'RSB_Form'];
        System.debug('Debug Log for Email Template'+et);
        if(!conLst.isEmpty() && et != null) {
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allMails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            List<String> email = new List<String>();
            for(Contact conObj : conLst){
                if(conObj.Opt_In__c == true && conObj.Double_OptIn__c!=true){
                    Id = String.isNotBlank(conObj.Id) ? conObj.Id : '';
                    System.debug('Debug Log for Id'+Id);
                    FirstName = String.isNotBlank(conObj.FirstName) ? conObj.FirstName : '';
                    System.debug('Debug Log for FirstName'+FirstName);
                    LastName = String.isNotBlank(conObj.LastName) ? conObj.LastName : '';
                    System.debug('Debug Log for LastName'+LastName);
                    ContactEmail = String.isNotBlank(conObj.Email) ? conObj.Email : '';
                    System.debug('Debug Log for Email'+ContactEmail);

                    email.add(ContactEmail);
                    //mail.setToAddresses(email);
                    mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{ContactEmail});
                    mail.setSubject('Nearly there! Please confirm subscription');
                    //mail.setSenderDisplayName('The Roundtable on Sustainable Biomaterials');
                    for(OrgWideEmailAddress owa : [select id, Address from OrgWideEmailAddress]) {
                        if(owa.Address.contains('rsb.org')) {
                             mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owa.id); 
                        } 
                     }
                    String text = et.htmlvalue;
                    System.debug('>>>>>>>text: '+text);
                    String filteredContent = '';
                    if(text.contains('{!Contact.Id}')){
                        filteredContent = text.replace('{!Contact.Id}',Id);
                    }
                    System.debug('>>>>>>>filteredContent: '+filteredContent);
                    if(filteredContent.contains('{!Contact.FirstName}')){
                        filteredContent = filteredContent.replace('{!Contact.FirstName}',FirstName);
                    }
                    if(filteredContent.contains('{!Contact.LastName}')){
                        filteredContent = filteredContent.replace('{!Contact.LastName}',LastName);
                    }
                    if(filteredContent.contains('{!Contact.Email}')){
                        filteredContent = filteredContent.replace('{!Contact.Email}',ContactEmail);
                    }

                    mail.setHtmlBody(filteredContent);
                    System.debug('Debug Log for mail'+mail);
                    allMails.add(mail);

                }
            }
            System.debug('Debug Log for allMails'+allMails);
            try {
                Messaging.sendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(allMails);
                System.debug('Email Sent Successful.');
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                System.debug('The following exception occured while sending email'+ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.debug('No record to iterate');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code almost correct except one small quick and small fix.

`Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();` declare this inside for loop.

```
for(Contact conObj : conLst){
    if(conObj.Opt_In__c == true && conObj.Double_OptIn__c!=true){
       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
```

Because you are adding same instance in the loop so it is sending email to single person.